# How to serve different size SVG graphic in css background image?

Tags: html, css, svg, media-queries

I am making a site with a media query for when the browser width is <768px.

When the browser is <768px, I want an SVG background image (my logo) which is 100x100 regularly to become reduced to 80x80.

Is this possible with SVG graphics to be reduced in size with media queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use % width for your Logo Image accroding to device the logo width and height will reduce.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible, some examples [here](http://my.opera.com/ODIN/blog/2009/10/12/how-media-queries-allow-you-to-optimize-svg-icons-for-several-sizes) and [here](http://jeremie.patonnier.net/experiences/svg/media-queries/test.html).

But, if you mean reduce the size you're probably talking more about the size determined by CSS, not by the svg itself (the svg should just redraw into the region given by CSS as long as it's done correctly).

Comment: Your second link is interesting, shows that the latest Safari doesn't support everything it should (e.g. printing of `img`; second row)